# Игнорирование совпадения и продолжение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, re, qregularexpression

Есть определенные строки, которые находятся в разным местах в большом файле:

```
... null='surveys' 
... null='section_items' 
... null='sections' 

etc.
```

Нужно найти совпадение `null=` или `null` и отталкиваясь от них изменить правую часть.

Моя попытка:

```
(?<!/*null='/*)(\w+['])
```

Comment: Попробуйте `(?<=null=')[^']*(?=')`. См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/d8zlWR/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew напишите это как ответ, я отмечу, спасибо большое. Не могли бы вы пояснить что означает '?=' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
(?<=null=')[^']*(?=')
```

Если символ `=` необязателен, если его может не быть, используйте

```js
(?<=null='|null')[^']*(?=')
(?:(?<=null=')|(?<=null'))[^']*(?=')
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/d8zlWR/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?<=null=')` - положительный блок предварительного просмотра назад, требующий наличия `null=` сразу слева от текущей позиции (`(?<=null='|null')` (PCRE, .NET, Java, ICU) / `(?:(?<=null=')|(?<=null'))` (Python, Notepad++, Boost) найдут позицию в строке сразу после `null='` или `null'`)
- `[^']*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `'`
- `(?=')` - положительный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий наличия `'` сразу справа от текущей позиции.